# What does "commission" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What does *commission* mean in this context:

> a volunteer who fixes up old, dilapidated houses for better community housing commission

I looked it up in the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/commission_1), but it doesn't seem to match any of the senses.

Source: The ILI English Series, *High-intermediate 3*, page 44

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is what the original said? **A** "Community Housing Commission"would be a governmental body of some kind whose mission was to improve housing options for the community, especially for those with low incomes. But I don't know what "better...commission" could mean here.

Comment: BTW, what is the noun that this phrase defines?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Just updated my question.

Comment: Even if the intended meaning has something to do with readying housing for  community use (to put more community housing in commission), the adjective "better" is not idiomatic as a modifier of "commission" (in that sense of the word).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: What if we take _better_ as a part of the proper noun:a volunteer who fixes up old, dilapidated houses for Better Community Housing Commission? Does it make sense?

Comment: "...for **the** Better Community Housing Commission" would be idiomatic, yes. But not without the article.  This is what I was suggesting in my first comment above.  "Better" could be part of its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary gives a good definition for this context:

> **[commission](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/commission)** (n):  a group of people who have been formally chosen and given the authority to get information about a problem or to perform other special duties:

However this particular question has a couple of confusing grammatical errors.  First of all, the name of the commission should be capitalized, to make it clear it's a proper noun.  Second, the name should include the definite article "the":

> ... for **the Better Housing** Commission

You would assume the people who write a test will use perfect English, but even native speakers sometimes make mistakes.

Side note:  No one *ever* says "a disorder that is a deficit in paying attention".  Again this is a condition with a proper name that should always be used and often capitalized

> ... with children who have **Attention Deficit Disorder**

or *ADD* for short.